# more sopisticated python post request (web scraping)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to acquire some data from polish gas system operator website.

Here is a site: http://en.gaz-system.pl/customer-zone/transmission/
Then link to "nominations"
Host is: https://swi.gaz-system.pl/swi/public/embed.seam
Then I change *Data (From)* and click Filter button

I want to use Python and request module.

My simple code:

```
    import requests
    swi_url = 'https://swi.gaz-system.pl/swi/public/embed.seam?viewId=E_PUB_043NN&lang=en'

    payload = {
    "embedsubview:subview_nomination_list_id:form_nomination_table_list_id":"embedsubview:subview_nomination_list_id:form_nomination_table_list_id",
    "embedsubview:subview_nomination_list_id:form_nomination_table_list_id:j_id17":"Filtruj",
    "embedsubview:subview_nomination_list_id:form_nomination_table_list_id:nominationTable:dayFromField:dayFromInputDate":"2015-01-01",
    "embedsubview:subview_nomination_list_id:form_nomination_table_list_id:nominationTable:dayToField:dayToInputDate":"2015-10-20",
     }

    r = requests.post(swi_url, data=payload)
    a = r.text
    print(a)
```

Response is not what I expect, because it returns the data of today's date

What should be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page HTML is not from a raw PHP or HTML document, but it seems to be dinamically generated from javascript scripts. You need to use selenium, Phantom JS, or Casper JS to scrape that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try with these softwares.